# How to select correct CUDA toolkit and cupy version + install on old GPU

Tags: cuda, cupy

I have an old GPU GTX 870m.

I installed cupy by instructions, but nothing worked.
At the same time, CUDA toolkit was installed successfully.

I try to use conda to install cupy and pip to install specific wheel version. It didn't help.

Easy sample don't work

```
import cupy

x = cupy.arange(6).reshape(2, 3).astype('f')
print(x.sum(axis=1))here
```

It displayed an error about problems with the driver

```
File "cupy\cuda\function.pyx", line 1, in init cupy.cuda.function 
File "cupy\_core\_carray.pyx", line 1, in init cupy._core._carray 
File "cupy\_core\internal.pyx", line 1, in init cupy._core.internal 
File "cupy\cuda\memory.pyx", line 1, in init cupy.cuda.memory 

ImportError: DLL load failed while importing driver
```

`conda info` shows:

```
virtual packages : __cuda=10.1=0
```

`nvcc --version` shows info about latest version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To correctly select the `CUDA toolkit` vesion you need:

- Check the driver version

  - For Windows in `C:\Program Files\NVIDIA Corporation\NVSMI` run `.\nvidia-smi.exe`
  - There is important driver version and the CUDA version.

```
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 426.00       Driver Version: 426.00       CUDA Version: 10.1     |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
.........
```

- If available, you should update the driver. In my case, this is last.
- [On the releases page](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-toolkit-release-notes/index.html) check the available versions of the CUDA toolkit (table 3)

  - You should find find the most accessible version of CUDA / check the desired version is available.

| CUDA Toolkit | Toolkit Driver Version Windows x86_64 Driver Version |
| --- | --- |
| CUDA 10.1 (10.1.105 general release, and updates) | >= 418.96 |

- You should find [on this page](https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-toolkit-archive) the installer of the desired version and install
- Type `nvcc --version` in the command line. Find a version, in my case it's `10.1.243`
- Install the appropriate `cupy`. I recommend using 'conda' because there is less headache.

`conda install -c conda-forge cupy cudatoolkit=10.1.243`

Should work.

`cupy` depends on the version of `CUDA toolkit`, and it cannot be higher than the card driver allows.